# Oracle: How to select current date (Today) before midnight?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Using Oracle, how do you select current date (i.e. SYSDATE) at 11:59:59?

Take into account that the definition of midnight [might be a little ambiguous](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/how-should-midnight-on-be-interpreted) (Midnight Thursday means Straddling Thursday and Friday or Straddling Wednesday and Thursday?).

Comment: Ambiguities should be sorted out with the person for whom you are doing this job.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To select current date (Today) before midnight (one second before) you can use any of the following statements:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1) - 1/(24*60*60) FROM DUAL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

What it does:

1. Sum one day to `SYSDATE`: `SYSDATE + 1`, now the date is Tomorrow
2. Remove time part of the date with `TRUNC`, now the date is Tomorrow at 00:00
3. Subtract one second from the date: `- 1/(24*60*60)` or `- INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL`, now the date is Today at 11:59:59

**Note 1:** If you want to check date intervals you might want to check @Allan answer below.

**Note 2:** As an alternative you can use this other one (which is easier to read):

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '23:59:59'  HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

1. Remove time part of the current date with `TRUNC`, now the date is Today at 00:00
2. Add a time interval of `23:59:59`, now the date is Today at 11:59:59

**Note 3:** To check the results you might want to add format:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1) - 1/(24*60*60),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '23:59:59','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Why do you need an expression to get a value which will never vary - it's a constant. Why don't you just concatenate `23:59:59` or `11:59:59 pm` to today date?

Comment: @Caffé: If all you're doing is displaying it, then that's fine. If you're doing any kind of processing on the date, then concatenating  the time onto it requires two type conversions, whereas the expression requires none.

Comment: @Caffé: Not sure if by concatenating one ends with another expression, could you provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: @Allan And if you are processing it, you should be able to simply add the known amount of time instead of be obligated to get this known amount of time from a calculation. Fortunately you can (see the Sylvain Leroux answer).

Comment: @Caffé: Whether you use the `1/(24*60*60)`, `0.00001157407` or `interval 1 second`, they're all interpreted by Oracle as the same thing. Anyone that's been using Oracle since before 10g, is more in the habit of using math directly, rather than `interval`. If you're going to do that, then `1/(24*60*60)` is somewhat more understandable than `0.00001157407`. You'll notice that, even in @Sylvain's answer that they're adding a day using `+ 1` rather than `+ interval 1 day`.

Comment: @Allan I was talking about readability and expressiveness, and I wanted to refer to the third Sylvain's example. I see no problem in using any other approach unless it were harmful to the business. I just flagged that it's good to have a more expressive approach as an option, and that this option could be better propagated.

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I dislike using one second before midnight. Among other things, if you're using a `timestamp`, there's a possibility that the value you're comparing to falls between the gaps (i.e. 23:59:59.1). Since this kind of logic is typically used as a boundary for a range condition, I'd suggest using "less than midnight", rather than "less than or equal to one second before midnight" if at all possible. The syntax for this simplifies as well. For instance, to get a time range that represents "today", you could use either of the following:

```
date_value >= trunc(sysdate) and date_value < trunc(sysdate) + 1
date_value >= trunc(sysdate) and date_value < trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day
```

It's a little more cumbersome than using `between`, but it ensures that you never have a value that falls outside of the range you're considering.

Comment: +1 It was not explicit in the question if the intent is the interval checking, but in this case it will certainly be a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

The real ambiguity is probably with [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) and maybe daylight saving (but I don't know if there is some case where it changes at midnight or not).

Anyway, for the usual case, there are few solutions:

```
-- all of these will produce a `DATE` result:
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)-1/86400 FROM DUAL;
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL;
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '23:59:59'  HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

---

Some little oddities if you use timestamps though:

- `TRUNC` will silently convert the value to `DATE`;
- Adding/subtracting a `NUMBER` to/from a `TIMESTAMP` will produce `DATE` too. 
  See [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref173)  for the details.

```
-- those two will produce a `DATE` *too*, not a `TIMESTAMP`:
SELECT TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '23:59:59'  HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP+1))-1/86400 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: The third option from your first set is perfect from readability and logical perspectives. It's good that Oracle provides this feature and it's sad that most people documenting solutions for this keep using weirder solutions.